# Complexity of a graph parity-coloring problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, colorings

Suppose I have a positively weighted (bounded-degree) graph $G$ where each vertex in $G$ is colored either black or white.  I'm curious about the complexity of the following problem:

Find a subset $S$ of edges of G of maximal weight, subject to the constraint that any node colored black is incident to an odd number of edges in $S$, and any node colored white is incident to an even number of edges in $S$.  The constraint is sort of a $2$-coloring up to parity.

The problem seems hard in general.  I'm more interested in the simpler case that $G$ is a tree.  In this case, are there any efficient algorithms to determine such a set $S$?  Also, does this problem have a name?

Comment: Try solving it on a tree using "dynamic programming" (i.e., recursion). For each subtree, solve the corresponding instances with both colors for the root.

Comment: On a tree the solution is very simple – work from the leaves up. Hence your correction (in a deleted comment) to the effect that there are no constraints on leaves is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note for each node $v$, there is a one-to-one mapping between the parity of incident edges in $S$ and that of incident edges in $\bar{S}$. This means we can consider the problem with minimum weight equivalently.

The minimum weight version is named min-cost T-join that is studied in [this note](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~naveen/courses/CSL851/lec6.pdf), which is an application of min-cost matching.

The idea is, one can decompose $S$ ($\bar{S}$ in the maximum weight version) into a set of edge-disjoint paths joining black nodes (nodes requiring an odd degree), thus the solution is exactly a min-cost matching of the complete graph induced by black nodes where the cost of edge $(u,v)$ is the length of the shortest path between $u$ and $v$ in the original graph. So this problem can be solved by [any algorithm solving min-cost matching](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/Lectures/Lecture11.pdf).

---

If the graph is a tree, the solution is much simpler as Yuval Filmus pointed out in the [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/94188/complexity-of-a-graph-parity-coloring-problem/94208#comment202984_94188).

> Try solving it on a tree using "dynamic programming" (i.e., recursion). For each subtree, solve the corresponding instances with both colors for the root.

Note for a tree, there is at most one feasible solution. So asking for maximum/minimum weight may be meaningless.